# How to use libimobiledevice to backup iphone on windows?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to develop a program that uses `libimobiledevice` to do backup work for `iPhones` on windows.But the documentation of `libimobiledevice` is so scanty, especially about the mobilebackup2 module.Can someone gives me some advice, flow of function or example codes?
Please forgive me for my crappy English and thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like a difficult question to answer.  Does the project not come with example/test programs that demonstrate its use?

Comment: Its official documentation briefly introduces the return value, parameter of each function.I searched for some code about it,but no useful results was found.